# Can't access array from inside object (uninitialized)

Tags: javascript, node.js

example.js

```
var ApiActions = {
  pendingAjaxRequests: [],
  addRequest: function() {
      this.pendingAjaxRequests.push(1);
  }
}

ApiActions.addRequest();

console.log( ApiActions.pendingAjaxRequests );

module.exports = ApiActions;
```

In another file:

```
var ApiActions = require("./example");
ApiActions.addRequest();
console.log( ApiActions.pendingAjaxRequests );
```

For some reason I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I can't seem to figure out why pendingAjaxRequests is not initialized? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
//define class with name 'ApiActions'. then you can just use 'var a = new ApiActions();    
var ApiActions = function(){
     //define class member(not static)
     this.pendingAjaxRequests = [];
     //if you define variable like this, they will only exist in scope of this function and NOT in the class scope
     var array = [];
};

//use prototype to define the method(not static)
ApiActions.prototype.addRequest = function(){
     this.pendingAjaxRequests.push(1);
};

//this will define a static funciton (ApiActions.test() - to call it)
ApiActions.test = function(){
     this.pendingAjaxRequests.push(1);
};
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what this code is doing?

Comment: @NateBarbettini, create class ApiActions and define 'pendingAjaxRequests' attribute that will be unique for each entity of this class(not static).
then define a function  'addRequest' that is not static too

Comment: Thanks. If you updated your answer with a thorough explanation like above, it probably wouldn't get downvotes :)

Comment: @NateBarbettini, look now